# Looking for one of B. Hornfeck's papers on odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x$, and call the ratio $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ as the *abundancy index* of $x$.  A number $N$ is called **perfect** if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

According to this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06081), it was **B. Hornfeck** who proved that different odd perfect numbers, $n_1 = {{p_1}^{i_1}}{m_1}^2 \neq n_2 = {{p_2}^{i_2}}{m_2}^2$ have distinct $m_i$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are primes.  That is:

> Claim: If $n_1 = {{p_1}^{i_1}}{m_1}^2$ and $n_2 = {{p_2}^{i_2}}{m_2}^2$ are odd perfect numbers and $m_1 = m_2$, then $n_1 = n_2$.

**Proof of Claim**

Let $m_1 = m_2$.  Since $n_1 = {{p_1}^{i_1}}{m_1}^2$ and $n_2 = {{p_2}^{i_2}}{m_2}^2$ are odd perfect numbers, we have

$$I(n_1) = I({p_1}^{i_1})I({m_1}^2) = 2$$
$$I(n_2) = I({p_2}^{i_2})I({m_2}^2) = 2$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{2}{I({p_1}^{i_1})} = I({m_1}^2) = I({m_2}^2) = \frac{2}{I({p_2}^{i_2})}.$$

Consequently:

$$I({p_1}^{i_1}) = I({p_2}^{i_2})$$

from which it follows that

$${p_1}^{i_1} = {p_2}^{i_2}$$

since powers of primes are [solitary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html).

We conclude that $n_1 = n_2$.

**QED**.

My question is:  Does anybody here have a reference to **B. Hornfeck**'s paper, where this claim is proved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper cites the book [*Not Always Buried Deep*](http://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-68) which cites this paper:

> Bernhard Hornfeck,
>   [Zur Dichte der Menge der vollkommenen Zahlen](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01901120),
>   *Archiv der Mathematik*
>   October 1955, Volume 6, Issue 6, pp 442-443, DOI: [10.1007/BF01901120](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01901120).

Comment: Thanks for checking!  An upvote for now.  Will double-check your answer in a few.

Comment: I see no reference to a result by Hornfeck on page 251 of  *Not Always Buried Deep*, as mentioned in that paper.